# Can I uninstall Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I had Ubuntu 16.04.4 on my HP nc6400 laptop.  I updated to 18.04.1 LTS.  Now the computer powers ON but there is no image on the screen.  The cursor is frozen in the bottom right corner of the screen.  The screen remains blank at all times.  I think  it has something to do with the graphics card in the computer.  I remember saying yes or checking a couple of boxes, but I don't remember what they were for.    I still have the 16.04.4 on a USB drive.  I have music, photos and other files on the laptop and don't want to lose them.   Can you help me get my computer up and running again?

Comment: If you boot the computer with 16.04.4 USB stick, you can copy the files from your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same HP laptop and problem.
There is a workaround. Ubuntu 18.04 boots fine if user auto-login is ON, and fails to boot if not. If you boot in recovery mode and then continue to boot by menu you will get to login screen and finally to the desktop. Copy your data, change in settings user auto-login to ON if you want to, then reboot. After that, it will boot without freezing.
I didn't find yet what causes that trouble.

Comment: Thank you, kaska & SurvivalMachine. I will probably do as SurvivalMachine suggest 1st.  But, kaska; how do I boot into Recovery mode?  I am unable to see anything on my desktop. However I am able to get into BIOS.